# ASP.net File Upload is saving empty files

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I'm using Ajax Async File Uploader to grab an image file and save it to a folder:

```
    if( file != null && file.hasFile)
    {
      if( file is the appropriate file type)
      {
        if( the filename is already taken)
        {
          add random numbers on the file name until it's unique
        }

        file.SaveAs( filepath + filename );
      }
    }
```

This works great on my local computer.  However, when I publish the program to the server the file will save in the correct location with the correct name, but the file size is 0.  I can't open the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my real code:

```
     // If cert has a file
    if(cert != null && cert.HasFile)
    {
    // If cert is the appropriate file type
    if((cert.FileName.IndexOf(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0) &&
    (cert.FileName.IndexOf(".jpeg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0) &&
    (cert.FileName.IndexOf(".tiff", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0) &&
    (cert.FileName.IndexOf(".png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0) &&
    (cert.FileName.IndexOf(".gif", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0) &&
    (cert.FileName.IndexOf(".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0))
            {
                // Popup warning
                Session["imagePopup"] = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                string filename = cert.FileName;

                // If image already exists randomly add numbers until a unique filename is found
                while( File.Exists(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateSavePath"] + filename))
                {
                    Random r = new Random();

                    filename = filename.Insert(0, r.Next(99).ToString());
                }


                // Save the new file
                try
                {
                    // save the file
                    cert.SaveAs(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificateSavePath"] + filename);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    error.Text += ex.Message + "<br />";
                }
```

Comment: Based on your pseudo-code everything is working great... So how about showing us the *real code* instead?

Comment: This sounds like a permissions problem.  Can you double check that the process your application is running under in IIS has permission to write and modify files in the folder you're trying to save to?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I was running the program like this:

I created a list view with editable rows.
The user can upload the images and the images are saved.
When the user click "Update" the images will be saved.

I changed it to this:

On the successful update event the image immediately saves.
Clicking "Update" simply refreshes the page.

Hope this helps someone